# How to use mysql join on or condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I have tried to construct this query which is to only choose records from the USER table if they appear in the FOLLOWER table, but keep getting a val.slide error.

Here is my query, please let me know if I am doing something wrong or how to better construct it:

```
SELECT * from USERS JOIN FOLLOWERS 
  ON (USERS.uid = FOLLOWERS.fid OR USERS.uid = a OR USERS.uid = b) 
WHERE FOLLOWERS.refid = 1
```

I tried this as well:

```
SELECT * from USERS WHERE (USERS.uid = a OR USERS.uid = b) JOIN FOLLOWERS 
      ON USERS.uid = FOLLOWERS.fid 
    WHERE FOLLOWERS.refid = 1
```

I am using nodejs with mysql.

UPDATE:
Ok let me add some explanation that may clear it up. I want all the settings info of the USER from the USER table, for two user ids that are not in followers and any followers from the user table that match the value of the followers ref id --- So ultimately I want back user A, user B, and user c,d,e,f if they match the ref id.

```
Table USERS:
uid: a, settings_on: true
uid: b, settings_on: false
uid: c, settings_on: true
uid: d, settings_on: false
uid: e, settings_on: false
uid: f, settings_on: false

Table FOLLOWERS:
fid: c, ref_id: 1
fid: d, ref_id: 1
fid: e, ref_id: 3
fid: f, ref_id: 2

Expected:
uid: a, settings_on: true
uid: b, settings_on: false
uid: c, settings_on: true
uid: d, settings_on: false
```

Here is the expected results:

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: how d is in result?

Comment: based on ref_id

Comment: then why not e?

Comment: It does not have the ref_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

Since you want `OR` conditions, you want an *outer* join, and because of *that* the follower condition must be in the join condition (otherwise you effectively get an *inner* join):

```
SELECT *
from USERS
LEFT JOIN FOLLOWERS ON USERS.uid = FOLLOWERS.fid
  AND FOLLOWERS.refid = 1
WHERE USERS.uid IN (a, b) -- either the user id matches
OR FOLLOWERS.fid IS NOT NULL -- or the follower condition matches
```

---

Replacing `USERS.uid = a OR USERS.uid = b` with `USERS.uid IN (a, b)` is not only easier to code and read, but typically performs vastly better (depending on how good the optimizer is) because typically only one index 
is chosen and only one expression is used to source values to look up in that index, so you'll find `a` quickly, but `b` will take a full scan or visa versa).

Comment: that does not seem to work and not sure if all of it makes sense.